# EF : using into statement with one single table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

With my EF5 I can do this for instance:

```
var result = (from p in entity.person
             join d in entity.dept on p.IdDept equals d.Id
             into dp from d in DefaultIfEmpty()
             select {
                 IdPerson = p.Id,
                 Depts = dp.Select(r => r.DepName).Distinct()
             }).ToList()
```

This is just an ugly example but it works fine, the use of the 'into dp' makes me manipulate the result and make my own grouping without having to use the 'group by' statement.

Now suppose I have only one single table, and I want to use the into statement :

```
var result = (from p in entity.person into pp ...
                 select {
                     something = pp.Select(r=> ...
             }).ToList()
```

the into statement here gives a compilation error when using a single table :

> A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

can anybody explain to me why ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but the `into` statement is used in linq normally for left joins as per my experience. In your case for single table you can directly use the entity again like:

```
var result = (from p in entity.person
             select {
                 something = entity.person.Select(r=> ...
         }).ToList()
```

Comment: but in your answer if you have a where statement, you have to repeat the conditions inside the select as well. On the other side when you use the 'into' statement , you don't have to repeat the conditions, you manipulate the result, that's the power of the into statement.

Comment: @MehdiSouregi that is the syntax for linq and it's normal thing